# ggplot line chart generated from OECD.stat with unwanted vertical lines in the chart

Tags: xml, r, ggplot2, time-series, linechart

I'm trying to follow [the post on R-bloggers](http://www.r-bloggers.com/reading-oecd-stat-into-r/) about sourcing the data from the [OECD Statistics](http://stats.oecd.org/). I modified the code from the post to source the data I would like to visualise:

```
require(XML2R)
file <- "http://stats.oecd.org/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetData/HEALTH_STAT/EVIE+EVIEFE00+EVIEFE40+EVIEFE60+EVIEFE65+EVIEFE80+EVIEHO00+EVIEHO40+EVIEHO60+EVIEHO65+EVIEHO80+EVIETOTA.EVIDUREV+EVIFHOEV+EVIHFEEV.POL+GBR+USA/all?startTime=1960&endTime=2013"
obs <- XML2Obs(file)
tables <- collapse_obs(obs)
keys <- tables[["MessageGroup//DataSet//Series//SeriesKey//Value"]]
dates <- tables[["MessageGroup//DataSet//Series//Obs//Time"]]
values <- tables[["MessageGroup//DataSet//Series//Obs//ObsValue"]]
country_list <- keys[keys[,1]== "COU" | keys[,1]== "COUNTRY"]
country_list <- country_list[(length(country_list)*1/3+1):(length(country_list)*2/3)]
dat <- cbind.data.frame(as.numeric(dates[,1]),as.numeric(values[,1]))
colnames(dat) <- c('date', 'value')
dat$country <- c(country_list[1], country_list[cumsum(diff(dat$date) <= 0) + 1])
dat$value2 <- signif(dat$value,2)
head(dat)
dat <- dat[complete.cases(dat),]
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat) +
    geom_line(aes(x = date,y = value, colour = country)) +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(colour = 'black', face = 'bold', size = 12,
                                    family = 'sans'),
          axis.text = element_text(colour = 'black', size = 12),
          plot.title = element_text(size = 17, face = "bold", colour = "black"),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
          panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = 'gray', linetype = 'dotted'),
          strip.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = NA),
          strip.text = element_text(colour = 'black', face = 'plain', size = 13),
          plot.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = 'black', size = 0.25))
```

However, the generated chart contains odd lines:
[image: ggplot with unwated lines]
I would like to know:

1. Why the lines appeared?
2. How can I remove them?

Comment: can you post a sample of `dat`?

Comment: It looks like you've got 17 to 21 rows of data values for each combination of country and date. Therefore, ggplot is drawing a line between 17 to 21 points within each country-year combination. Since the values of those points range from about -3 to 80, the vertical lines through those points extend from about -3 to 80 in each year. Could it be that your download script is downloading a bunch of different measurements that should be in separate columns, but are all ending up in a single column (values)?

Comment: For example, EVIE, EVIEFE00, EVIEFE40, EVIEFE60, etc. are separate statistics (life expectancy or some other health statistic) and should all be separate columns of data, but instead they're all stacked together into the single column called `values`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, you were right. I had multiple units selected in the variable, the [plot looks fine now](http://cl.ly/image/1J1n0u2H1B2z) and the correct URL is `http://stats.oecd.org/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetData/HEALTH_STAT/EVIEHO00.EVIHFEEV.POL+GBR+USA/all?startTime=1960&endTime=2013`