# ggplot line plot not connecting points

Tags: ggplot2, linechart

I'm trying to create a simple line plot charting number of crimes per year from 2006-2015 for each county in California. Problem is the points are all connected, not separate lines. Data frame looks like so:

```
enter c 'data.frame':   7319 obs. of  69 variables:
 $ Year               : int  2006 2006 2006 2006 2006 2006 2006 2006 2006 2006 ...
 $ County             : chr  "San Bernardino County" "Los Angeles County" "Alameda County" "Alameda County" ...
 $ NCICCode           : chr  "Adelanto" "Agoura Hills" "Alameda" "Alameda BART" ...
 $ Violent_sum        : int  136 41 221 193 545 0 7 54 297 38 ...
```

Trying to use the following:

```
 ggplot(calicrime, aes(x=Year, y=Violent_sum, color=County)) + geom_line()
```

Rendered plot:

[image: rendered plot]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ggplot(calicrime, aes(x=Year, y=Violent_sum, color=County, group = County)) + geom_line()`

Comment: I tried that but got the same output: http://imgur.com/eE92tfB

Comment: Is it possible there are multiple measurements for a county within the same year? [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29449377/ggplot-line-chart-generated-from-oecd-stat-with-unwanted-vertical-lines-in-the-c?rq=1)

Comment: That was exactly it, thank you @bouncyball